# php while loop database data

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

the below while loop statement loops mysqli query result(text and image from database). A row can contain text only or image and text. I'm trying to display text only if the image field is empty and display both image and text when they both exist in a row. However, i tried using the if statement in the while loop statement below, the problem is that when it suppose to display only text,it displays text with image tag with no `src` value,kindly help fix this.
Thanks.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $text = $row["texts"];
    $image =$row['images']; 
    if(!empty($text) && !empty($image)){
        echo '<img src='.$image.'/>';
        echo '<div>'.$text.'</div>';
    }elseif( !empty($text) && empty($image) ){
        echo '<div>'.$text.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: We cannot help here, since we do not know the data you are working with.

Comment: So what does `$image` actually contain _exactly_?

Comment: @arkascha image location url

Comment: You want to think about that last comment again, I suggest.

Comment: If this is echo'ing the `<img>` tag, `$image` is not empty. If you `var_dump($image);` what does it say for those cases where it's now echo'ing an empty `<img>` tag?

Comment: I would put an "echo 'in the if statement<br/>';" just after the if and "echo 'in the elseif statement<br/>';" just after the elseif. If you see the 'in the if statement' you know that $image actually isn't empty, but isn't quite what you had expected. If you see the 'in the elseif statement' then the image tag must be part of your $text. My money is on the 'if' branch.

Answer (score 0):

`$row['images']` might contain spaces, try trimming it. Also, you can simplify the `if`:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $text = trim($row["texts"]);
    $image = trim($row['images']); 
    if(!empty($image)){
        echo '<img src='.$image.'/>';
    }
    if(!empty($text)){
        echo '<div>'.$text.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $id = $row["id"];
   $text = $row["texts"];
   $image =$row['images']; 

   if($image)
      echo "<img src='{$image}' />";
   if($text)
      echo "<div>{$text}</div>";

}
```